# mysql - finding users who login from the same ip

Tags: mysql

I'm running a dating site and i want to find out which users have more than one profile.

i have a userlog table with (userid, ip address) and i want to find all users who login from the same ip address - i only want the results where more than 1 user logs in from the same ip.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What if two people that work together use the site?

Comment: Or if they use mobile internet (in which case thousands of smartphone users may share an IP)? Don't assume anything from just the IP.

Comment: A typical _I know it's broken, please don't make me fix it_? So I gather suggestion about what you _can_ do are unwelcome? OK, no matter, it's broken, it's your site, you decide :)

Comment: Note that when using a smartphone, my ("external", i.e. publicly routable, not NATed) IP address changes approximately every 10km (6 miles). I'm assuming my cellphone provider has an IP address pool that's geographically divided - and yes, on some sites it happens quite often that I get an address that's "blacklisted" because someone else got banned, and the site has an IP-ban to go with that. This is not your grandfather's Internet: NATing and IP address reuse will only get *worse*, what with IPv4 depletion and all that. (Reverse also applies: proxies+VPNs+Tor, infinite "IPs" to come from!)

Comment: Guys just to close this side-discussion, IP matching is only one tool we use out of several tools to detect user duplication, no one tool alone is perfect, but the sum of the parts is greater than the individual value of each. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a simple `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` so I'm going to assume this is what you want:

```
SELECT "ip address"
FROM userlog
GROUP BY "ip address"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will give you all the IP addresses of those users. To get the actual users:

```
SELECT "ip address", userid
FROM userlog
WHERE "ip address" IN (
    SELECT "ip address"
    FROM userlog
    GROUP BY "ip address"
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY "ip address"
```

Comment: Hi there, what if the same user logs in 10 times with the same ip ? This will be returned in the first query as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sherif Buzz Not sure if this works in MySQL, but `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) > 1` may give you what you want...

Comment: @djacobson: That will work, but will not scale well (not in MySQL 5.0 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Your query would look something like this...

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[password]);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email' && password = '$password' && ip = '$ip'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
//What you want to do if it matches with an already logged ip
}
```

Good luck.